# Excel charts +C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I am using excel to draw charts from c#, but i need the chart to be one series related to each other not two series (when i select a range that has two columns of data)
can any one help:

```
        xla.Visible = true; 
        Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
        Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

        // Now create the chart.
        ChartObjects chartObjs = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        ChartObject chartObj = chartObjs.Add(100, 20, 300, 300);
        Chart xlChart = chartObj.Chart;
        Range rg = ws.get_Range("B2", "C17");
        xlChart.SetSourceData(chartRange, XlRowCol.xlColumns);
```

thanks

Comment: I am confused on what you are trying to do.

Comment: when you have tow column of data in excel and select them and insert chart, it can generate ether tow series of lines in chart or can generate one series (ie:line) which is relative to both columns as if first column is x-axis and the second is the y-axis, i need to do this in code not the tow series as i mentioned

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cleaned the code up a bit and added the generation of random data so this should run on its own.

```
Random random = new Random();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xla.Visible = true;
Workbook wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);

Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

// Now create the chart.
ChartObjects chartObjs = (ChartObjects)ws.ChartObjects();
ChartObject chartObj = chartObjs.Add(150, 20, 300, 300);
Chart xlChart = chartObj.Chart;

// generate some random data
for (int row = 0; row < 16; row++)
{
    ws.Cells[row + 2, 2] = row + 1;
    ws.Cells[row + 2, 3] = random.Next(100);
}

Range xValues = ws.Range["B2", "B17"];
Range values = ws.Range["C2", "C17"];

SeriesCollection seriesCollection = xlChart.SeriesCollection();

Series series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
series1.XValues = xValues;
series1.Values = values;
```

Comment: +1! Tried your code but got a COM Exception at this line `SeriesCollection seriesCollection = xlChart.SeriesCollection();`

Comment: @GETah - It might mean that you did not install the charts or did not create the chartObj correctly. If you want help with this you'll need to provide more details (what exception, what are you doing) and ask a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I actually used your code in a standalone VSTO application if that helps

Comment: @GETah - The code was not written or tested in a VSTO application. You should be able to do something similar but it will be different.